# For a Main-Class in a JAR Subfolder, what is the correct setting for "Class-Path:"?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a JAR structured like this:

```
 myHello.jar
 |
 +-- folder
 |   |
 |   +-- mypackage
 |       |
 |       +-- Hello.class
 |
 +-- META-INF
     |
     +-- MANIFEST.MF
```

That is, the Class `mypackage.Hello` is in the subfolder `folder`.

I've tried all manner of values for Class-Path: in the Manifest, but I always get...

> Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.Hello

Currently, the Manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: folder/
Main-Class: mypackage.Hello
```

All the JarFile Spec says is this:
"The value of this attribute specifies the relative URLs of the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs."

How can this be done using a subfolder?
(no I do not want to put it in the Root & use the usual value ".")

Comment: AFAIK it cannot be done (unless you write/use a non-standard, self implemented class loader) - assuming `mypackage` is the declared package of Hello: 1) the `mypackage` folder must be in root; 2) `Hello.class` must be in the `mypackage` folder.

Comment: 1. You can't reference folders *inside* the jar file from the `Class-Path` property, only jar files and directories *next to* (i.e. in the same directory or some directory under that). 2. Is your `Hello.class` really *next to* the `mypackage` subdirectory or is it inside of it (it should be the latter).

Comment: @Joachim Hello.class indentation corrected.

Comment: @user16320675 Actually, I'm using the Eclipse Jar-In-Jar Classloader, but I edited it out to make this posting more succint. And I'm trying to tell the JiJ-Classloader to look in a subfolder but, as Catweazle said: "Nothing Works".